# Laravel 5 Difference between staging and production server

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5 APP that is returning different results for a query on the staging and production servers. They are admittedly quite different...

The method I'm calling on my 'Answers' model looks like this:

```
/**
 * Get answer for Question
 *
 * @param int
 * @return App\Answer
 */
public function getAnswer($question_id)
{
    if(count($this->answers) > 1){
        $answer = $this->answers->where('question_id', $question_id)->first();
        if($answer){
            return $answer;
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty straight forward.

On my staging and development servers it works a treat. But on the live site it returns nothing. When I copy the live database to the staging or development servers it works fine. Both my Staging and Live servers are running CentoOS but I assume it's somehow related to PHP configuration.

When I change the method to just look over the answers and return the one with the correct `question_id` it works fine.

Comment: Have you check the $question_id passed properly? then the if clause is passed? try breaking down the code till you reach the problem, It will be more easy then. Also check the table names, if you are on window and moving to linux, Capitilization will result in different behaviour

Comment: Thanks @SherKhan. Yeah, I've done all that. The breaking point is that nothing is returned from the 'where' query. Both the Staging and Live sites are running Linux and it's only the live site I'm having trouble with so I don't think it's a capitalisation issue. I've also dumped the database from the live onto the staging server which didn't break the staging server..

Comment: Then compare your PHP configuration of both environments and also dump the results of the query regardless of whether answer>1 or not, so that you can have a clue what's returned from database, I mean simplify the query firts

Comment: I guess I'm trying to get a sense of what to look for in the PHP config as I'm sure that's where the issue is. `$answer > 1` returns true. the issue is the `where` query doesn't return any results.

Comment: It can be, remove the ->first() and check if it returns all answers or not

Comment: If I remove the `->first()` it returns an empty Collection Object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104056/discussion-between-sher-khan-and-hammygoonan).

Comment: I think you have not handle the condition when the null is return by the query you have to handle that to avoid this error.

Comment: Thanks @AlankarMore. It's definitely not that though. When I run the raw SQL query it returns what I expect it to. Moreover, the database is identical on the staging and live sites. It's only not working on the live site.